# How to authenticate user on backend service using OpenId Connect

Tags: authentication, web-applications, openid-connect

I'm trying to find a way to authenticate user of front web application, who is authenticated by OpenId Connect Code Flow, on backend REST services, which currently support OpenId Connect Code and Implicit flows.

Problem is, that this backend is front for some mobile apps and they use it directly. So I want web app to be something like a proxy between user and backend. Maybe there is some part of spec I'm missing, that describes something like WS-* ActsAs or OnBehalfOf scenarios? Or best practices?